# how to load another form in <div> tag without loading header and footer in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").click(function(){
    alert("jquery working."); 
     $("#mydiv").load("welcome/signup");
    });
    });
    </script>
```

In my login form contains

```
 <input type="button" value="Sign Up!" id="signup"/>
```

I have written this code in head section of my header. I have one controller named              welcome one function defined in it named signup. now I have created a login form in which I have created a button with id="signup" which is shown above. Now when user clicks on that button I want `signup.php` form to be loaded in `#mvdiv` without loading the whole page.

For testing purpose I wrote that alert and it is working means the code is working fine but that page is not loading on that `<div>` tag.

Thank you!!

Comment: have you created a modal to load up

Comment: No but cant i load it through controller

Comment: you want to load a form in the page is this you want I can guide you what to do next.

Comment: Yeah I want to load another form replacing the existing form which is inside #mydiv

Comment: well exactly I have share a link in my answer you go through the link and you will find your self comfortable.

Comment: How do i implement it in my code? help me pls I am a beginner

Comment: ok I have give a little description in my answer and I have also added another link please follow and than if you get some problem let me know

Comment: and if you find my answer help full than please do not forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write smth like this:

```
$("#mydiv").load("welcome/signup #formId");
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The script he has written is fine the problem is he want to load a Modal where another form will be appear